# Detecting hard coded values in application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jslint, jshint

Is there any library/configuration/tool or something similar to run javascript check and warn about hard coded values in the code?

Something similar to jscheck.

Comment: How would a tool like this work? How should it differentiate between values that must be hardcoded (classes, ids...) and values that should not be hardcoded?

Comment: Define what should be found.  Just strings/numbers, or something more?  Hard coding isn't inherently wrong, but rather context dependent as to whether it is appropriate or not. I would imagine this would be quite difficult for a tool to do with much accuracy.

Comment: I understand that this isn't a trivial task for a tool, but i thought that since jscheck can detect things like max complexity maybe there are tools powerful enough to warn (even if not 100% accurate) about hardcoded values

Comment: Can you please explain to me wich "hard coded values" should be warned of?

Comment: It's not a problem of difficulty,  as both Jace and idmean correctly pointed out.  It's simply a matter of arbitrary definition of the same level as "toe-may-toh" vs "toe-mah-toh". One is not better than the other, unless in your specific scenario, you define it so.

Comment: Any hardcoded values. For example if (myUserType === 13) - should issue a warning

Comment: why would ` if (myUserType === 13)` be bad?

Comment: Yeah, not sure about the question. Did you mean `if (myUserType === 13)` is bad, or that `myUserType === 13` is bad? The first isn't bad. The second probably misunderstands `===`. Did you want `myUserType` to use something like an enum instead of literal values? That's not really what a linter does, especially in a dynamic language like JavaScript. I might [also] vote to close unless the question can be made clear. ??

Comment: I'm really not sure where the confusion comes from. `if (myUserType === 13)` is bad because if i have this condition in multiple controllers for different purposes and then the type (13) changes - i would have to change it in every piece of code where the condition exists. If i had `if (myUserType === config.someValue)` - i'll need to change only in config.

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Comment: Yes, thank you for taking the time to answer but it's not what i meant.

Comment: @jvrnt Linters don't do what you're asking. And, within reason, they really can't. I mean, how would they know `13` is a "type"? I can't see a generic tool saying you can't use *any* constant integer values *anywhere*. Also, how does this question deserve the angular tag? But, anyhow, no, JSLint and JSHint do not warn you of constant integer usage. Just regexp for digits and troll through your code.

Answer (score 0):

This might be not a total answer to you question, but TypeScript could help you!

> TypeScript is a typed superset of JavaScript that compiles to plain JavaScript.
>   http://www.typescriptlang.org/

[example `if(myUserType === 13)` here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=var%20myUserType%3A%20string%0A%0Aif(myUserType%20%3D%3D%3D%2013)%20%7B%0A%7D)